# How to display the first 10 characters only of a message stored in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my inbox view, where I am able to list each individual message, I want to display the first 10 characters of a message if the message is larger than 10 characters or display the entire message. The user can then click on the message to view the entire message.

```
message.body
```

is where the contents of the message are stored in the database.

Comment: What about truncating the message?
Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
truncate(message.body, :length => 10)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `truncate`. Link for the documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate

Answer (score 1):

To have a string with a total of 10 chars (including the ... at the end)

```
message.body.truncate(10)
```

or to cut to end of last complete word

```
message.body.truncate(10, separator: /\s/)
```

Examples:

```
"some simple words here that is too long".truncate(23)
 => "some simple words he..." 

"some simple words here that is too long".truncate(23,separator: /\s/)
 => "some simple words..."
```